# HTML/CSS: How can I push the footer downwards indefinitely?

Tags: html, css, footer, responsiveness

So far, I have managed to get my footer to always stick to the bottom, however, I have been struggling to get the content or images on my webpage to push the footer down. I have been trying absolute, fixed, relative positions for the footer but to no avail as the content in the class "container2" continues to go under the footer. It also shouldn't be sticky footer similar to the nav bar but like a natural footer where it is pushed down by content.

HTML/CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/jof0hzhc/2/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="app">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>ResponsiveNav</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"> </script>

</head>
<body class="bg2">
    <div class="wrapper">
            <header>

                  <nav>

                        <div class="menu-icon">
                              <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="logo">
                              ResponsiveNav
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu">
                              <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> <!--Classifying the button as "activepage" will allow the button to be red when the user is on the page.-->
                                    <li><a href="apps.html" class="activepage">Current page</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </div>
                  </nav>

            </header>

            <section class="content">
            <p class="apphead">Heading</p>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                <div class="container2">
                <p class="apptext">Sub-heading</p>
                    <div class="games">

                        <img src="images/1.png">
                        <img src="images/2.jpg">
                        <img src="images/3.jpg">
                        <img src="images/4.jpg">
                        <img src="images/5.jpg">
                        <img src="images/6.jpg">
                    </div>

                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                </div>


            </section>




      </div>


<footer>
<p class="foot">
        Footer text. <br>
        __________________________________________________________________________________________________ <br> <br>

        <a href="about.html" class="inquiry">About us </a> 

        |

        <a href="contact.html" class="inquiry">Contact us</a> <br>

        __________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
        <section>
            <p class="foot">Social Media</p>
                <span class="social">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/mail.png" alt="Mail" width="50px" height="50px"/></a>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="50px" height="50px"/></a>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="50px" height="50px"/></a>
                </span>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>All rights reserved<br></h3>
        </section>
</p>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 98%;
      background-color: black;
      min-height: 100%;
}

body {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif; /*Keep this font or hamburger disappears*/
      font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
      width: 98%;
      height: 13vh;

}

li>a{display:;}
li>a:hover, /*li hover makes the area around the list of text have a block of color around it when you hover over the text*/
li>a:focus{color:red;text-decoration:underline;} /*li focus is when you select the element, the element gets into a focus*/


footer { /*How do I even make the footer always stick at the very bottom no wonder the dimensions of the browser?*/
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    height:300px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:black;
    border-width: 10px;
    color: white;


}


p {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

a { /*General styling for links to other pages or websites*/
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
}

h2 { /*Styling for site title*/
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align:left;
    color:white;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: courier;
}

h3 {
    font-size:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    color: white;
}




.content { /*the main container that consists of most of the existing content*/
    margin-top:5px;
    width:100%;
    height: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;


}

.logo {
      line-height: 60px;
      position: fixed;
      float: left;
      margin: 16px 46px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
}


nav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 60px;
      z-index: 1; /*Allows for the navigation bar to stack on top of content and not appear as it overlaps*/
}

nav ul {
      line-height: 60px;
      list-style: none;
      background: black;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: right;
      margin: 0;
      padding-right: 40px;
      transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
      background: orange;
      opacity: 10;
}

nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
      line-height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #000;
      text-align: right;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 15px 24px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: orange;
      display: none;
}

.activepage { 
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.welcome {
    font-family: courier;
}

.inquiry {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
}


.container2 {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 97.8%;
    height: 1000px;
    z-index: 0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;

}

p.heading {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: courier;
}

.foot {
    color: white;

}

.bg2 {
    background-image:url("hex.jpg");
    height: 550px;
    width: 102%;


}

.apphead {
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: courier;
}

.apptext {
    color:white;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: courier;

}

.games {
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    border:solid white; 
}

.games img {
    width: 640px;
    height:250px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: 1s;

}

.games img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.item img{
    display:block;
}


@media(max-width: 786px) {

      .logo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            margin-top: 16px;
      }

      nav ul {
            max-height: 0px;
            background: #000;
      }

      nav.black ul {
            background: #000;
      }

      .showing {
            max-height: 34em;
      }

      nav ul li {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 24px;
            text-align: center;
      }

      .menu-icon {
            display: block;
      }

}
```

Comment: You should not be using the br tag like you are. This is bad practice. Markup is not meant to style your page for you.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I am a bit confused why you are using the `<br>` tag so much, but it almost looks like you are trying to space the elements with them. You may want to use padding or margin to do that.

Lastly, I think what you are looking for is `position: fixed`. Try this:

```
footer { 
  width:100%;
  position: fixed; /* use fixed instead of absolute */
  bottom: 0; /* set bottom to 0 */
  height:300px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:black;
  border-width: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the images don't go under the footer now but the footer shouldn't be sticky like the sticky navigation menu. How can I make it so the footer can only be seen when I scroll to the end of the webpage? I mean as in the content/images having to push the footer downwards, not just have the footer stick to the bottom of the window and having to see it all the time as you scroll down like a nav bar.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your css. The main problem for your content not to appear is that you're using `overflow: hidden;` in `container2` and `height: 1000px;` this causes everything that exceeds 1000px won't be show. Try removing `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: x-scroll`.

This is the documentation for the overflow property, I suggest you read it for a better understanding of your problem. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you should change 1. you are using absolute position outside relative 2. using absolute values for hight is not good practice 3. is always better use padding and margin to make space ect. Keep fixed position only for header nav and comment out all fixed hight values(px)and absolute and relative positioning to start with. Absolute position should be inside relative if there is not special reason not to do that. To get out from main problem start with footer and container2. But there is lot more to fix.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need set a `min-height` for `html, body {min-height: 100vh;}`
2. Set `footer` as `position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0;`

Hopefully this will help you.